# Best practices to alter a SQL Lite table in Room on a published app

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, google-play, android-room

I recently posted an app on the PlayStore. The application is built with Kotlin and according to the MVVM architecture. The data is stored using Room. So my question is this: If some users have already installed my application and I want to make an update that changes the format of my database (e.g. adding a column in a table), how can I make sure that these users can get this update without losing their data already saved ?
Any insights or best practice advice would really help me a lot. Thanks !

PS: I can publish code if necessary

Comment: Use Room Data Migration [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions)

Comment: @GGK Thanks a lot this is exactly what I needed